# How to load 3d object on runtime in Unity 3D

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to load 3d object on runtime. This 3d object(may be any ".fbx" file format like in Qualcomm Sample project ""ImageTarget" contain "teapot.fbx") load from any saved folder or in iphone from shared directory. If someone know please help me on that, this will be great help for me.

Comment: Have you tried [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: Make sure if you follow Kay's suggestion you note this from the docs:  "The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the assets folder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They question is do you really want to load a model from **ANY** folder.

If so, generally you would use [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW.html) class to load stuff. Though as far as I know Unity won't automatically convert your **.fbx** file into a model if you load it with **WWW**. Unlike textures from images. You will have to parse it yourself. Which is easy in case of an **.obj** file but I don't know much about **.fbx** format.

I don't know if you can use [C# File API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) in an Android app.

Other ways don't allow you to load model from **ANY** folder. These are:

- Resources.Load which loads a file from Resources folder into memory. Resources folder is compiled in a big packed file in the final build.
- Load files from StreamingAssets folder whose are not compiled in an assembly but left as is. [Though as I see not in Android app](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).